# If/Else statement not working - only one image button works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make it so that I can move between two popup images. Either image pops up correctly.

How can I have both the first and second part of the if/else statement to work (how can the right arrow work in both images)?

Prior research I have conducted includes google searches. Most of the following code has been obtained directly from or help by videos on youtube.

```
$(function() {
    "use strict";

    $('.postOneImageOne, .postTwoImageOne, .postTwoImageTwo').click(function () {
      var $src=$(this).attr('src');
      $('.show').fadeIn();
      $('.img-show img').attr('src', $src);
    });

    $('span').click(function () {
      $('.show').fadeOut();
    });

    $('.next').on('click', function() {

      // This loops through each img tag
      $('img').each(function(){

        // Now you can use $(this) to look at each img tag's class
        if ($(this).hasClass('postTwoImageOne')) {
          console.log('if works');
          var $src2 = $('.postTwoImageTwo').attr('src');
          $('.img-show img').attr("src", $src2);
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('postTwoImageTwo')) {
          console.log('else works');
          var $src3 = $('.postTwoImageOne').attr('src');
          $('.img-show img').attr('src', $src3);
        }

       });      

    });

  });

 $posts.=
            "<div class='container'>
            <div class='form'>

            <img class='profilePicture' src='P2Includes/monkey2.jpg' alt='profilePicture' >
            <h1>$title</h1>
            <h2>$$price</h2>
            <h3>$user_uid</h3>
            <h4>$date</h4>
            <textarea readonly rows='9' cols='62'>$content</textarea>
            <div class='postImageContainer'>

            <img class='postTwoImageOne active' src='P2Includes/purplespace.jpg'             
        alt='postPicture'>
            <img class='postTwoImageTwo' src='P2Includes/puppy.png' alt='postPicture'>

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class='show'>
            <div class='overlay'></div>
            <div class='img-show'>
            <span>+</span>
            <div class='previous' id='previous'>V</div>
            <div class='next' id='next'>V</div>
            <img src=''>
            </div>
            </div>";
```

When I try to move to the next image from the first image by clicking the right arrow, I get "if works else works" seven times in the console and the arrow doesn't work. But when I try to click the next right/next arrow in the second image then I get "if works else works" seven times in the console and the arrow does work. Below the JavaScript I am echoing out $posts in a while loop.

Comment: Everything including and after `$posts.=` is not valid JavaScript. Please provide code that others can reproduce, preferably using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552).

Comment: Are you using PHP? `.=` is string concatenation for PHP, not JavaScript